# When can *quis* be used as an adjective interrogative pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, interrogative

The interrogative pronouns *quis* and *quī* have me rather confused.  I understand that *quis* is generally substantive, while *quī* is generally adjective.  But Allen and Greenough (§148) indicate that quis is "very common as an adjective, especially with words denoting a person," and then they provide two examples:

> quis diēs fuit? *what day was it?*
>   quis homō? *what man?*

From what I can tell, only one of those two examples has anything to do with their "especially with words denoting a person" category, which leads me to believe that additional guidance might be available.

Broadly speaking, what are the categories in which *quis* is frequently used as an adjective interrogative pronoun?  In such categories, is a distinction in meaning made between *quis* and *quī*?

Comment: I'd say adjectival *quis/quid* is uncommon, and I think it can often be explained away as a different construction: *quis [est] homo?* = "who is that person?"; *quis dies fuit?* = "what was that day?". It would be interesting to look at some real examples. As to a distinction in meaning, I don't think there is be any. Two real examples: http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23quis%20dies Note also that *quis* can be short for *quibus*. More examples, mostly from comedy: http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23quis+homo&first=21 Note that many of those passages are different constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeanne Marie Neumann, in *Lingua Latina: A College Companion*, suggests

> You will sometimes find *quis* (i.e. the form of the interrogative pronoun) used instead of *quī* (the form of the interrogative adjective) **before a noun** in **questions of identity**: *Quis servus? Medus.* [emphasis mine]

In a previous answer, @fvogel offered these examples, all of which meet the conditions Neumann imposes:

From Horace *Satires*:

> Quis homo hic est? (I.6)

From Plautus *Miles Gloriosus*:

> Quis homo id vidit? (176)
>
> Quis homo in terra te alter est audacior? (313)
>
> Quis homo sit magis meus quam tu es? (615)

I find another set of examples in Cicero, *In Catilinam* II:

> O fortunatam rem publicam, si quidem hanc sentinam urbis eiecerit! Uno mehercule Catilina exhausto levata mihi et recreata res publica videtur. Quid enim mali aut sceleris fingi aut cogitari potest, quod non ille conceperit? **quis** tota Italia **veneficus, quis gladiator, quis latro, quis sicarius, quis parricida, quis testamentorum subiector, quis circumscriptor, quis ganeo, quis nepos, quis adulter**, quae mulier infamis, **quis corruptor iuventutis, quis corruptus, quis perditus** inveniri potest, qui se cum Catilina non familiarissime vixisse fateatur? quae caedes per hosce annos sine illo facta est, quod nefarium stuprum non per illum?

In *A Preparatory Course in Latin Prose Authors*, Albert Harkness writes of this paragraph,

> *Quis*, though more commonly used *substantively*, may be used *adjectivally*, when, as in this case, the inquiry relates, not to the *character* of the person or thing, but to the person or thing itself. Thus *quis veneficus* is not *what kind of poisoner*, but *what* poisoner, *i.e.*, which one.

It's interesting, though, that Cicero uses *quis* here only for masculine nouns, but for *mulier infamis* he uses *quæ*. I wonder whether *quis* as a noun is used in place of adjectival *qui* but not adjectival *quæ*.

Comment: That quote from Harkness seems to take *qui* awfully close to *qualis*. Does he make a difference between these two?

Comment: He doesn't seem to. On the other hand, I haven't read the whole thing. If I do (and if he does) I'll update.